# in react key prop is stripped

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am generating a list of TSX elements with:

```
    this.productsModel = this.state.products.map(o => (
            <Grid.Column key>
```

However, react warns me:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

So with the recommended practice [1] I add:

```
    this.productsModel = this.state.products.map((o, i) => (
            <Grid.Column key={i}>
```

But `key={i}` is stripped out at rendering, whatever is the element (`Grid.Column`, `div` etc).
How comes? How to solve this?

[1] https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: please the read the document carefully . React don't recommend to use `index`  as key `We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change`

Comment: As @prasanth said react does not recommend using indexes for keys. [here are the official docs of keys and indexes](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and also [here is the post](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) react recommends that explains it better

Comment: Actually this is really not a problem as I'm not generating elements. Elements are well defined and ordered and fetched from a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

key element is not supposed to be passed to the DOM, its a reserved props for React optimization only

So when you add key like

```
  this.productsModel = this.state.products.map((o, i) => (
        <Grid.Column key={i}>
```

The key is not even passed to the Grid.Column component but stripped by read while actually passing all the props

You also need to provide a unique key for the elements returned from within the map function

> Key is provided for react to keep track of elements being rendered, so
>   that if an element is deleted or the list is sorted, it need not
>   re-mount everything but compares the correct elements during its
>   virtual DOM comparison. In this way it actually improves performance

Using indexes a keys doesn't provide much of a benefit even though the warning is removed. It better you use a unique id from each product object within your products array as key

Comment: Fine, unique_id (`o.id` generated with `shortid`). But this does not answers "how to remove the warning".

Comment: Adding key prop should remove the warning. otherwise warning maybe coming from some other mapped loop too

Comment: But the key prop is stripped (but not id). I still have the warning with `<Grid.Column id={o.id}>` which becomes `<div id=XXX class="column"`.

Comment: What I meant was that the warning should go away once you add a key prop. If it doesn't maybe you are getting the warning at some other place too

Comment: In the answer you said "The key is (...) stripped by read", and in the comment "once you add a key prop". Can you clarify ?

Comment: key is not passed onto the dom but needs to added in the code

Comment: How do you do that ?